# Checking a string array's words and their first letter

Tags: java

I am a beginner coder at my Uni. We are tasked with reading a text file, verifying all the first letters of each word are capital, and then they are put in alphabetical order. I am trying to tackle one point at a time. So I decided to go with verifying all the first letters are capital by just making my own array of words and then figuring out how to do it from a text file after. This is what I have so far and it's nothing

I have tried Character.isUpperCase(arr.charAt(0));
but i am gettin an error

```
public void sortStrings() throws IOException {
    String[] arr = {"Zebra", "test","Butter"};
    String[] arr2 = {"Legends","Apex","Best"};

    for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if(Character.isUpperCase(arr.charAt(0)));
    } 


Cannot invoke charAt(int) on the array type String] is the error I am getting with arr.charAt(0)
```

Appreciate any tips !

Comment: what is expected result?

Comment: That's a compile error, because arrays don't have a method called `charAt`.  That's a method on a String object.  So, how do you get a string object from an array?

Comment: The expected result would be to.. Let's say I have a text file with .. "Sara , John, Abraham"
It would first verify each word starts with a capital, then it would put them in alphabetical order. So it would be Abraham, John, Sara

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot the index to access the item in your array. Replace `arr.charAt(0)` with `arr[i].charAt(0)`

```
String[] arr = {"Zebra", "test","Butter"};

for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if(Character.isUpperCase(arr[i].charAt(0)))
        doSomethingHere();
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I will work with this and go from there. I appreciate the help.

Comment: Just a quick question, just to see if I am on the right track of thinking. Can I check each word of the array and then sort them alphabetically in this one for loop?
Also, I CANNOT use java library methods ( i think they are called) like .sort.. I would love to use arrays.sort

Comment: not sure I understand. You can or your can't use `Arrays.sort`? And for sorting you should probably do it separately, gets you cleaner code

Comment: @TylerR, What are you supposed to do if the first letter of a word is not in upper case? Do you still sort it?

Comment: I cannot use Arrays.sort. Okay, I will do it separately. If it does not start with an Uppercase letter I need it to print "Invalid input. Word found which does not start with an uppercase letter." If the word starts with a number, it needs to be , "Invalid input. Word found which does not start with a letter."

Comment: @molamk It's presenting a challenge to sort alphabetically too because I can easily to integers because of the < and > being able to apply to numbers. Can you use the same kind of syntax for letters? like saying a > z?

Comment: You can also apply `>` to _characters_. Or use the `compareTo` function to compare `Character` objects. It also works for `String`, which can be really useful for sorting algorithms

Comment: @molamk Thank you. I will definitely implement that then. Thank you

Comment: Glad to be of help buddy. Don't forget to mark this as _answered_ so future users know the solution to your question too

Comment: @molamk I don't wanna spam these comments, but I got questions regarding importing words in a file into an array of strings(I have been searching for an understandable way on google for about 90 mins now). My instructor is very unclear on what he meant by java built in methods I cannot use. Idk if I can even use compareTo. Definitely cannot use array.sort

Comment: @TylerR sure. Just post a new question here on StackOverflow, people will answer. I'll check it later if it's up. Also reminder to mark this as answered so others know the answer